# SolrJ keeps indexed files open

Tags: java, solrj, solr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SolrJ addFile keeps documents open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984306/solrj-addfile-keeps-documents-open)

Hey guys,

I'm quite new to Apache Solr. My situation is the following:

When my application starts up, it scans a directory and adds all pdf-Files in that directory to the Solr Index (Using SolrJ's ContentStreamUpdateRequest):

However, the application also utilizes JNotify to watch over the folder, so that it can update Solr's index in case a file changes.

The problem is the following: After the initial scan of the directory, everything is working fine, all file handles are removed after the respective files have been streamed to Solr. But if a change within the directory occurs (such as renaming a file), SolrJ just doesn't seem to let go of the changed file's handle, thus it can no longer be modified.

What am I doing wrong here? (The snippet below is both used for the initial scan and when a file changes)

```
protected boolean addDocument( File doc ) throws IOException, SolrServerException {

    ContentStreamUpdateRequest csur = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest( "/update/extract" );

    csur.addFile( doc );
    csur.setParam( "literal.id", Utils.getAbsolutePath( doc ) );
    csur.setAction( AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true );
    NamedList<Object> result = solr.request( csur );

    return result != null;
}
```

thx for any suggestions in advance