# SolrJ addFile keeps documents open

Tags: java, solrj, solr

I've already submitted a similar question, but I've broken down the problem to its simplest form, so I'm gonna post it again:

The problem is, that SolrJ seems to keep file handles open, if I add the same file more than once.

I use the following method to submit a document to Solr:

```
public boolean addDocument( File doc ) throws IOException, SolrServerException {

    ContentStreamUpdateRequest csur = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest( "/update/extract" );

    csur.addFile( doc );
    csur.setParam( "literal.id", Utils.getAbsolutePath( doc ) );
    csur.setAction( AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true );
    NamedList<Object> result = this.solr.request( csur );


    return result != null;
}
```

And this method to remove documents:

```
public void removeDocument( File doc ) throws IOException,
        SolrServerException {

    this.solr.deleteById( Utils.getAbsolutePath( doc ) );
    this.solr.commit();
}
```

But that seems to leave some File Handles lingering:

The following snippet demonstrates the problem:

```
File doc = new File( "../../testpdf/bbb.pdf" );
solr.addDocument( doc );
//solr.removeDocument( doc );   // Without these 2 lines, all handles
//solr.addDocument( doc );      // are released correctly
```

If I add the same document twice, SolrJ somehow keeps the handles alive, and the added document cannot be modified by any other processes.

I've already tried calling using `csur.addContentStream()` instead of `csur.addFile()` in `addDocument` and then closing the underlying Stream and Reader of the added stream, with no effect.

thx for any suggestions in advance

Comment: Are you sure it's Solr and not Jnotify itself? Take a look who's holding file open. This would be a good start

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's Solr. I've tested a little more now, and the behaviour is quite strange. Sometimes, files also stay locked after the initial scan. Maybe it's due to some lazy-loading stuff that SolrJ does.

Comment: kk, it's definitely something SolrJ-specifig. I've removed everything but 2 calls to `addDocument` with the same document. After the first call, the file-handle gets freed, but when I do the second call, the handle stays.

Comment: Are you using embeddedSolrServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't fix it, did a workaround by writing a custom ContentStream that buffers the document.