# SOLRJ and indexing files 

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying to index an email messages complelety with subject, body and all the attachments. For indexing I'm using common SolrInputDocument. How can I add attachments into document to be indexed? I have found the similar post here [SolrJ keeps indexed files open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979244/solrj-keeps-indexed-files-open) but it only shows the way, how to index files separately from document data. How can I index files as being part of the other email message data like subject, body, sender etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you also want the text inside the text to be searchable too? In case yes, then take a loot at Tika which helps reading files in RTF, PDF etc format.

In case not, you can just store the path and filename of the attachments in your index and the attachements locally at some path.

Comment: Yeas I need to index files content. I know tika but trying to understand the API. Only way to index files (seems to me) is to index them separately using ContentStreamUpdateRequest csur = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest( "/update/extract" ); csur.addFile( doc );  but in my case, the attachments are part of email message so I need them to be indexed as a part of the message data.